# GameOver scene loaded whenever the screen is clicked

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Firstly, this is my script:

```js
#pragma strict

var incorrect: AudioClip;
var correct: AudioClip;
var anything: GameObject;
var diamond: Sprite;
var circle: Sprite;
var triangle: Sprite;
var square: Sprite;
var number: int;
var AcceptInput: boolean = true;

static
var score: int = 1;

var guiScore: GUIText;


function Start() {

    number = Random.Range(1, 4);

    if (number == 1) {
        anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = diamond;
    } else if (number == 2) {
        anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = circle;
    } else if (number == 3) {
        anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = triangle;
    } else {
        anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = square;
    }
}


function Update() {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        if (AcceptInput) {
            AcceptInput = false;
            Debug.Log("Clicked");
            if (anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite == diamond) {
                audio.PlayOneShot(correct);
                guiScore.text = "Score: " + score;
                StartCoroutine("YieldTestEnumerator");

                AcceptInput = true;
                number = Random.Range(1, 4);
                if (number == 1) {
                    anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = diamond;
                } else if (number == 2) {
                    anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = circle;
                } else if (number == 3) {
                    anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = triangle;
                } else {
                    anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = square;
                }

            } else if (anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite == circle) {

                Debug.Log("Wrong Answer!");
                Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
                audio.PlayOneShot(incorrect);

            } else if (anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite == triangle) {

                Debug.Log("Wrong Answer!");
                Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
                audio.PlayOneShot(incorrect);

            } else if (anything.GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite == square) {

                Debug.Log("Wrong Answer!");
                Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
                audio.PlayOneShot(incorrect);

            }
        }
    }
}

function YieldTestEnumerator() {
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.5);
}
```

As you can see it is a multiple choice game. For some stupid and weird reason, if I press ANYWHERE on the screen, it would just load the "GameOver" scene, even though I got the correct answer. Why does it detect a touch from ANYWHERE on the screen? Thats just so weird. Does any of yous have any ideas how to fix this? I don't get this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your indentation by indenting with (multiples of) 4 spaces in appropriate locations. Right now your code is near impossible to read.

Comment: is that better? @Bart

Comment: Not really, but I think I fixed it. Have a look at the difference and make sure it's still correct. First one is free. ;)

Comment: So I assume you only want the action to happen when a specific item is clicked? I see nothing in your code where you check if that is the case. You right now merely respond to a click and don't filter any further.

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is when you press down the button, check if the sprite of another object is diamond. If it is then add 1 point. then chnage the sprite again. if it isn't, then load scene gameover, now, for some weird reason, I press anywhere on the screen it takes me to the gameover scene @Bart

Answer (score 0):

Attach a collider 2D to your **anything** and work with

```
OnMouseDown()
{
    var lSprite : Sprite ;
    lSprite = GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite  ;
    if (lSprite == diamond) {
        audio.PlayOneShot(correct);
        guiScore.text = "Score: " + score;
        StartCoroutine("YieldTestEnumerator");

        AcceptInput = true;
        number = Random.Range(1, 4);

        if (number == 1) {
            lSprite = diamond;
        } else if (number == 2) {
            lSprite = circle;
        } else if (number == 3) {
            lSprite = triangle;
        } else {
            lSprite = square;
        }

    } else 
    if (lSprite == circle) {

        Debug.Log("Wrong Answer!");
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
        audio.PlayOneShot(incorrect);

   } else 
   if (lSprite == triangle) {

        Debug.Log("Wrong Answer!");
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
        audio.PlayOneShot(incorrect);

   } else
   if (lSprite == square) {

        Debug.Log("Wrong Answer!");
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
        audio.PlayOneShot(incorrect);

   }
```

}

Comment: you are clicking on anything?

Comment: No, the reason I had a variable for anything is because it is a different object. The script I showed you was for a button and if you clicked it it checks the sprite for anything and add score.

Comment: I tried to add a collider2d to other things as we'll but didn't work

Comment: The script must be attached to an object with a collider2d and you must be clicking on that object. To be sure you are clicking on the object add a Debug.Log ("Clicking!") to the start of OnMouseDown.

Comment: No no no no, you don't understand what I'm saying. The script above is for a button, like the buttons in a multiple choice game

Comment: And how are you displaying your buttons?

Comment: So basically I have 4 buttons pretty much the same code but the others are the circle button triangle button and square button. I display it side by side

Comment: Are they gameobjects with colliders?

Comment: Yep, the weird thing is I press anywhere on the screen and it loads the game over scene

Comment: did you attach this to the multiple choice button object?

Comment: Yes, have you figured out the answer yet? Thanks for the time though